# How to change page URLs to "www.site.com/page" instead of "example.com/blog/page" but keep post URLs as "example.com/blog/post"?

Tags: url-rewriting, pages, urls

I would like to make it so the URLs of my pages (created in the Wordpress dashboard) show up right after the domain name instead of after the blog directory.

I have installed Wordpress in a directory called **blog** which is located in the **public_html** directory. When I make a *page* from the Wordpress dashboard it will by default appear under the blog directory like:

```
www.site.com/blog/page
```

What I would like to do is take advantage of Wordpress's built in 'pretty URL' styling but use them outside of the **blog** directory where Wordpress is installed. So for example:

```
www.site.com/page
```

When I try to manually create a page, add it in public_html directory and view it on my site it looks like:

```
www.site.com/page.html
```

I don't like the trailing `.html` because it is not clean looking and just extra unneeded info for the visitor.

***UPDATE:***

Also keep in mind that I would also like to keep the URLs of each *post* looking like:

```
www.site.com/blog/post
```

So to sum it up:

**How can I make my Wordpress *page* URLs look like** `www.site.com/page` **while having my Wordpress installed in** `www.site.com/blog` **as well as having my *post* URLs looking like** `www.site.com/blog/post` **?**

Answer (score 2):

You just set the WordPress directory in your WP General Settings to your top-level URL  (www.site.com/), then copy index.php to the root directory of your site and modify it to load content from your actual wp directory.

Step by step instructions are here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory

I did this for my personal web site: http://dannythorpe.com.  The WP files are actually located in a subdir of the web root (public_html), not the web root dir.

No URL rewriting is required!

Comment: dthrope, unfortunately this did not solve my problem and this is due to my unclear explanation of my problem. I have updated the question. Anyways, after following the instructions you sent me, I tested my site out and realized that my **posts** and **pages** showed up like `www.site.com/post` and `www.site.com/page` respectively. The first problem is that I'd like the **posts** to be showing up like `www.site.com/blog/post`. The second problem is that the content of the WP created **pages** is not being displayed. The URL of each **page** is fine though.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is just to install WordPress in the root directory instead of in the subdirectory /blog/.

Then if you want posts still to appear in /blog/ you can edit the permalinks structure in your Settings to include that.

Comment: Gesher, I am trying to make this as streamlined for my client so I can't do work arounds like this. There has to be a solution to this.

Comment: @classer: There is not. If you have the WP site installed in /blog, then /blog is required on all WP URLs. This isn't a WordPress limitation, it has to do with how webservers work.

Answer (score 0):

### Success!

All I had to do was install WP in my root and then go to Settings > Reading > Front page displays > and then select 'blog' as my 'posts page'.

For my front page I used a custom template that I created from this tutorial http://www.wordpressmax.com/customize-wordpress/custom-page which is semi dated but the info is still accurate.

Comment: Isn't this what I said?