# How to mask url of a specific page without affecting seo

Tags: url-rewriting, seo

What I'm looking to do is exactly [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9781/how-do-i-make-page-urls-look-like-www-site-com-page-instead-of-www-site-com-b) and/or [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/15742/how-to-prepend-route-with-blog-for-blog-listing-page-only).

What's holding me back is my fear of losing all the SEO traffic my posts at site.com/blog/post have already acquired.

Would implementing this fix negatively affect the page rankings of my posts and if so, by how much?

Comment: Take a look into 301 redirects and/or the rel canonical tag.

Answer (score 1):

Well you are changing URLs which WILL impact your SEO.  The best way to minimize this is with what's known as a "301 redirect".

The 301 part is a server response code to tell the visitor (Googlebot is the one you care about) that the resource formerly at domain.com/page is now permanently moved to domain.com/blog/page.

If done properly you can modify your URL structure w/o taking a rankings hit.

Here is the format for your situation. Paste these in your .htaccess file after the Wordpress section:

```
# Old URL redirects
redirect 301 /oldpage/ http://www.domain/new/page
redirect 301 /oldpage2/ http://www.domain/new/page2
```

You will create a new redirect line for each URL that is changing.  Over time, Google will pickup on the 301 code and update their index with your new URLs, assigning the page rank from the old URL to the new page.

---- EDIT ----

To run Wordpress in a sub-directory without including that path in your URL structure, you probably want something like this article [Giving Wordpress its Own Directory](http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory)

Comment: Thank you for the reply! If I didn't want to move my current wordpress directory... (and thus avoid the need for the redirects) would it be possible for a page at site.com/blog/page to have a vanity url at domain.com/page.

Comment: Yes.  Wordpress will run fine in a subfolder while powering a site at the root level.  By way of example, you can have the Wordpress files sitting a domain/blog folder but your site URLs can still be domain/page.  There is good documentation on that that I can share.

Comment: Yes, I would be very curious to see any documentation you have on that. Thanks again

Comment: Sorry - failed to point out that I added that information to my answer.  See --edit-- above.

Comment: ah yes, But if I go down that route I will have to the 301 redirects to avoid taking a rankings hit. I'm hoping to find a solution where I can have a wordpress powered page point to site.com/page however maintain the wordpress directory where it is now at site.com/blog...

Comment: I must be missing a piece of information here. What format are your URLs now?

Comment: No worries, it might be my fault for not being clear enough. My current format has my wordpress directory *named* "blog" sitting in my site's root. So my admin page is at site.com/blog/wp-admin and a post is at site.com/blog/post. I also have a wordpress page at site.com/blog/page that I would like to have at simply site.com/page without however needing to move my wordpress directory.